# Error : Cannot resolve method

Tags: java

I was trying to create a program that had multiple characters with different attributes. I ran into an issue calling a method I (tried) to define in Class Character.

```
public class CharacterAttributes
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Character John = new Character("John", 0);
       workout(5);
    }
}
class Character
{
   private String name;
   private int Str;
   public Character(String n, int initialStr) 
   {
      name = n;
      Str = initialStr;
   }
   public void workout(int byAmt) {
      Str = Str + byAmt;
   }
}
```

The compiler said the "workout()" method could not be resolved.

Thanks!

There's probably a lot of errors, honestly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method belongs to class `Character`, so you should call it against the instance `John`:

```
John.workout(5);
```

As a side note, it is conventional to start the name of a variable with a lowercase (`john` instead of `John` and `str` instead of `Str`), and to give them names that reflect their type (`Str` gives a hint that it's a `String` while it is in fact an `int`).

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, if you would like to call the method `workout` the way you're doing, you can move the method to the `CharacterAttributes` class, and change it so that it takes a reference to the `Character` instance that will be updated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character John = new Character("John", 0);
    workout(John, 5);
}

public static void workout(Character character, int byAmt) {
    // use a setter to set the attribute
    character.setStr(character.getStr() + byAmt);
}

class Character {
   private String name;
   private int Str;
   public Character(String n, int initialStr) {
       name = n;
       Str = initialStr;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public int getStr() {
       return Str;
   }
   public void setStr(int str) {
       Str = str;
   }
}
```

Comment: The main problem I wanted to solve, before I came across this, was to try to make the "workout()" method work for all characters I created. How would I go about doing this?
Thanks for that though, I was stupid not to think of that.

Comment: What do you mean by _make the "workout()" method work for all characters_? It is already "working" for any `Character` object you create.

Comment: I mean that I would like to be able to use the method so that it adds 1 to the str variable of the Character I specify.
So, if I had another Character Simon, it would add one to Simon's str. If I called the method for John again, his str would be 2, and Simon's would be 1 still.

Comment: @JasonGuo If I understood you correctly, this can be done by having the method take the `Character` instance as a parameter; see my edit.

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do workout(5)

you did this

```
Character John = new Character("John, 0);
```

so you do:

```
John.workout(5)
```

and sorry but your conventions are pretty bad

`public int Str` should be `public int str`

Comment: Alright, will do. Don't want to form a habit as I'm just starting to learn.

Comment: and 1 more thing what you are trying to do here Str = Str + byAmt; could be Str += byAmt; that just means it adds it to Str this also exists "-=" that means it decreases the amount